# How to increase return values of functions without breaking legacy code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, let's say you have a function:

```
def foo(a): 
    return a
```

And there are heaps of legacy code which uses this function:

```
amount = 4 + foo(a)
```

What if I need to increase the return values of `foo` without breaking the existing codes?

```
def foo(a)
   return a, a + 5
```

Now, when I do this, variable `amount` is not the correct answer, because `a` is now, in pylint's words 'a tuple' so `amount` will change from returning `a + 4`, to returning `(a, a+5) + 4`.

How do I add `a + 5` to `foo`, while still allowing amount to be a single scalar value, rather than a tuple?

Comment: Depends on the actual situation. Can you use non-placeholder code?

Comment: Why can you not just warp this function in another function and call that wrapper when you need it and it won't affect the legacy code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
def foo(a, new_usage=False):
    if not new_usage:
        return a

    return a + 5
```

Then call your function like this for all new usage situations:

```
foo(a, True)
```

For example, your old code would still work:

```
In [40]: amount = 4 + foo(4)

In [41]: amount
Out[41]: 8
```

And for new usage, you could do this:

```
In [42]: amount = 4 + foo(4, True)

In [43]: amount
Out[43]: 13
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted -- this seems to be exactly the route I would take. Perhaps add an example showing how `foo(a)` will still return the original behavior?

Comment: thanks! This seems to work, and is elegant enough I think. Will accept answer when I can

Comment: This is a horrible thing to do in general—but as a solution to an inherently horrible problem, that's kind of unavoidable. I think it's still much better to just create a separate function, as suggested by juanpa, but in the rare cases where you can't do that, this is probably the best alternative.

Comment: you solved the problem but creating another problem; you just blew up the encapsulation (OOP). whenever you need to make a change you just modify your original implementation!?

Comment: I just posted what I think is a more elegant solution (albeit 2 days late). Check it out if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution is to make `foo` a class that extends `int` (or `float`, depending on the output of your legacy `foo()`) instead, while implementing the `__iter__` method to allow it to be unpacked as a sequence when used in a sequence context:

```
class foo(int):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self, self + 5))
```

So that:

```
amount = 4 + foo(1) # used as an int
print(amount)
a, b = foo(1) # used in a sequence context so foo.__iter__ is called
print(a, b)
```

would output:

```
5
1 6
```

But of course, the above code works only because in your question, `foo(a)` simply returns `a`, and that just happens to be the behavior of the `int` constructor, so by extending `int`, `foo(a)` also conveniently returns `a`.

If your `foo(a)` actually returns anything other than `a` in your production legacy code, however, you will need to override the `__new__` method so that it returns a new `int` instance of a different value.

Below shows an example if your legacy `foo(a)` returns `a + 1`:

```
class foo(int):
    @classmethod
    def __new__(cls, type, a):
        return super(foo, cls).__new__(type, a + 1)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self, self + 5))
```

So that:

```
amount = 4 + foo(1)
print(amount)
a, b = foo(1)
print(a, b)
```

Would output:

```
6
2 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the function and add the new return value.
Then write a wrapper named like the original function, which extracts the legacy return value:

Original code:

```
def foo(x):
    return a
```

New code:

```
def enhanced_foo(x):
    return a, extra_info

def foo(x):
    return enhanced_foo(x)[0]
```

Legacy code still works:

```
a = foo(x)
```

New code uses the new name:

```
a, extra = enhanced_foo(x)
```